# Get posts from similar time as current post

Tags: wp-query, date

Hi guys I've been struggling with this for a while and wondered how you lovely people would go about implementing it.

I would like to show 4 posts that were posted before and after the current post. Ideally two from before and two after. But here's the rub: I need there to always be 4. So if there aren't 2 newer ones fill the 4 from older ones or vice-versa.

Which queries would you run? Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you worked on this yet? If yes, please share with us!!

Comment: I'm afraid I've not had much time to get back this. Will hopefully soon.